# Gitlab notifying default approvers

Tags: gitlab

Is there any solution out of the box gitlab offers regarding sending emails for default approvers!
In other terms: if I am a default approver for a project X, then I want to receive an email whenever a new merge request is open in this project !
This is doable in bitbucket, not sure if it is the case also with gitlab.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a global setting for

> sending emails for default approvers

However, you can make use of [Custom Notifications](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/notifications.html#notifications-on-issues-merge-requests-and-epics). They can be set at a project or a group level by the approvers themselves.

For example, you can click the bell icon in a given project and select **Custom**. By default *Failed pipeline*, *Fixed pipeline*, and *Moved project* are enabled in Custom notification events. You can then enable notification on *New merge request* as well.

[image: Notification icon]

[image: Custom notification events]